# How to fix Ambiguous occurrence ‘find’?

Tags: haskell

I'm new to haskell and I'm trying to run a piece of code but I'm getting this error: 
"Ambiguous occurrence ‘find’
    It could refer to either ‘Data.List.find’, imported from ‘Data.List’ at sequential.hs:1:1-16 (and originally defined in ‘Data.Foldable’) or ‘Main.find’, defined at sequential.hs:5:1"

```hs
import System.IO
import Data.List


find :: String -> FilePath -> IO (Maybe FilePath)
find s d = do
  fs <- getDirectoryContents d                         -- 1
  let fs' = sort $ filter (`notElem` [".",".."]) fs    -- 2
  if any (== s) fs'                                    -- 3
     then return (Just (d </> s))
     else loop fs'                                     -- 4
 where
  loop [] = return Nothing                             -- 5
  loop (f:fs)  = do
    let d' = d </> f                                   -- 6
    isdir <- doesDirectoryExist d'                     -- 7
    if isdir
       then do r <- find s d'                          -- 8
               case r of
                 Just _  -> return r                   -- 9
                 Nothing -> loop fs                    -- 10
       else loop fs
```

Comment: fyi: it's easier for people to run your code (and thereby figure out what's wrong with it) if you post the source, rather than a screenshot. You can use triple-backticks (``` ...```) to make it format nicely.

Comment: Your edit includes the fix suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56047435/1126841); that either destroys the premise of the question, or you still have a problem that you aren't describing.

Comment: I've removed `hiding (find)` from the question because otherwise it looks like you asked "I have this problem: <code that has no problem goes here> how do I fix it?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change line 1 to `import Data.List hiding (find)`, assuming you never intend to use the `find` defined there.

Answer (score 2):

In your situation your options are:

1. Rename your own `find` into something else.
2. Import `Data.List` as qualified: `import qualified Data.List`. You can add `as L` to shorten code that uses stuff from `Data.List`.

Comment: Or, since `Data.List` is a pretty large library, just import specifically those few functions you actually need: `import Data.List (sort)` seems to be enough here, and it's not too painful to add a few more functions if you need them

Comment: Or just use the fully qualified name `Main.find` in the code.